# Debian's ReportBug equivalent on Fedora/Gnome?

Tags: debian, fedora, gnome, distributions, bugs

When I was using Debian, there was a tool called [`reportbug`](https://packages.debian.org/reportbug).

Ironically, the tool itself was probably the buggiest program I have ever used. I was never, ever actually able to make a successful bug report in the graphical mode.

However, the tool seems to be a good idea. I don't have to go through some online identification process, or do any browser-business - I'd just fire up a program, fill out a few forms, and that was it.

Is there something like that for the Fedora operating system? Or for Gnome itself?

Because, sometimes, I encounter weird bugs and errors, and I think it would come in handy to have such a tool at my fingertips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Command Line Tools

- There is a Fedora-specific command line interface to bugzilla provided by the `python-bugzilla` package.  This may be the closest to thing to Debian's `reportbug`.
- As an alternative, you can try the generic command line interface provided by the `pybugz` package.  However, this is not a Fedora-specific tool.
- There is another Fedora-specific command line tool called `perl-Fedora-Bugzilla`.  However, this package has been orphaned and it may not be compatible with the latest version of bugzilla that Fedora is using<sup>1</sup>.

### GUI Tool

- Fedora uses **Automatic Bug Reporting Tool** (`abrt`).  In most installations it is enabled and running by default.  It is supposed to automatically fire a notification when a program crashes and guide you through the appropriate steps to file a bug to bugzilla.redhat.com.  You can launch it manually and review the previous crash reports by going to *Activities* and typing `abrt`.

  Unfortunately, this tool cannot be used to create whatever bug you want.  The bug must be based on a crash that the tool noticed.

<sup>1</sup> See [Bug 823417](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823417)

Comment: `abrt` is heavily impaired by the fact that it doesn't let you report bugs manually - and it's a hindrance to UX if users need two different tools for various classes of bugs...

Comment: I will use the first option, I suppose. To which address should I file Fedora-related bugs?

Comment: It looks like I was mistaken about `bugzilla`.  I've corrected the answer so that it's Fedora-specific (you don't need to specify an address to submit Fedora bugs).  Also, the tool is provided by the `python-bugzilla` package, not the `bugzilla` package.  Sorry for the mistakes.